# Including a massive Vector in header file

Tags: c++, gcc

So I have a massive vector that I load line by line from a file in C++ using an std::ifstream object. This works, but I was thinking, hey why don't I write the vector to a .cpp file like below and just #include it as a header:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vectorOfGates2 = { {
"Q_OR04 g359(.A0 (i2), .A1 (i1), .A2 (i0), .A3 (i3), .Z (ptm_replace_0));",
},
{
"Q_OR04 g357(.A0 (i2), .A1 (i1), .A2 (ptm_replace_0), .A3 (i3), .Z (ptm_replace_1));",
"Q_INV g358(.A (i0), .Z (ptm_replace_0));",
},
{
"Q_OR04 g357(.A0 (i2), .A1 (i0), .A2 (ptm_replace_0), .A3 (i3), .Z (ptm_replace_1));",
"Q_INV g358(.A (i1), .Z (ptm_replace_0));",
}};
```

When I do this with a small vector and #include the file it works (vectorOfGates is in a file called vector.cpp that I just include). However GCC gives me a segmentation violation error if I try it with a big vector (it takes like three minutes of trying to build to cause this error:

```
 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/framework_roman_src_rtl.dir/MappingSingleton.cpp.o
/grid/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0p2/bin/g++  -DBUILD_TO_RUN_WITH_XCELIUM -DET6=ET6 -DLINUX2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -I/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/ua/Framework/Roman/src/x86-lx2-64 -I/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/ua/Framework/Roman/src -I/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/ap/include -I/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/ua/Framework/include -I/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/ua/include -I/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/sys/avs/xlm/19.03/s1/include -I/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/sys/include/x86-lx2-64  -std=c++14 -g   -pthread -g -Wall -Werror -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/framework_roman_src_rtl.dir/MappingSingleton.cpp.o -c /grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/ua/Framework/Roman/src/MappingSingleton.cpp
g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/framework_roman_src_rtl.dir/MappingSingleton.cpp.o] Error 4
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/ua/Framework/Roman/src/cmake-build-debug'
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/framework_roman_src_rtl.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/grid/cva/p4_02/hisham/gcc/ua/Framework/Roman/src/cmake-build-debug'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong? The same size vector loads if I try doing it using a ifstream line by line, so I don't wknow what's different here. Thanks.

Comment: Is loading the vector from a file an issue?  If not I would suggest doing that.  It gives you the benefit that the binary is smaller and you can change the data in the vector without having to recompile the source code.

Comment: @NathanOliver Binary size is not an issue for my needs, but runtime preformance is. I would rather not have to wait for the ifstream to load the lines one by one.

Comment: Compilers often have trouble compiling huge auto-generated files, they run out of memory or take forever. You could play with the compilation options (remove `-g`, `-O1` might help (or hurt), etc). You can also check if a different version of the compiler handles it a bit better. You could try intermediate sizes to see how far you are from something that works.

Comment: Can you do other things before you have the vector populated?  i.e. start the program, startup a thread to read the data into the vector, do other things while that thread is running.

Comment: Does the type absolutely have to be `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`? Some flat structure that you could mmap would be much faster to read ;-)

Comment: A large static array that can be built at compile time (`const char *vectorOfGates2[][MAX_SUBVECTOR_SIZE]`), possibly constructing the `vector<vector<std::string>>` (or `vector<vector<const char *>>` if that can work for you) may be an option.  The compiler will have to generate a huge number of constructor calls with your implementation.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm const char *vectorOfGates2[][MAX_SIZE] seems to work. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @user3586940 *hey why don't I write the vector to a .cpp file like below and just #include it as a header:* -- The issue with doing this is if any of that data changes, you need to edit that data in your source code and rebuild your program.  Programmers would want to stay away from setups that have them rebuild their program just because the data changes.  Also, there are many programs that require time to load the data *once*, but when that is done, it's done.  So I don't understand your claim of "runtime performance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to declare you array in a way that only uses static data, with no constructors needing to be called.  Then the entire thing will be compile time data.  Something like

```
const char *vectorOfGates2[][MAX_SIZE] = {
    { "string1" },
    { "string2", "string3" },
    // ...
};
```

Where MAX_SIZE is a constant that holds the maximum number of entries for any particular row of the vector.

If necessary, this can be converted to a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` (or `std::vector<std::vector<const char *>>`) upon program startup, depending on how you need to use it.  But leaving it as the static array would use the least amount of memory, as no dynamic memory would need to be allocated.